# Define private properties in C# like Typescript

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-core

Is there a syntax in C# that allows me to define a private property, like in Typescript?

Example: Typescript:

```
constructor (private field1: string) { }
```

In C# I have to do this:

```
private readonly string field1;
public MyClass(string field1)
{
    this.field1 = field1;
}
```

### update 1:

I'm looking for a syntax sugar for AspNet core dependency injection.

Comment: Ok, no problem about this.

Comment: 'I'm looking for a syntax sugar for AspNet core dependency injection' : It is hard to see how your original question has anything to do with dependency injection, or ASP.NET. Please create a new question and don't change completely a question you have already asked and that already has answers.

Comment: The exact equivalent of the Typescript feature doesn't exist in C# as of version 7, but it's [coming](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/records.md).  It will most likely arrive in C# 8, the next version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no syntactic sugar for this in C# 7, you'll have to write the boilerplate.

Sounds like primary constructors are sort of what you're looking for - they were in C# 6 beta but ultimately dropped.

http://www.alteridem.net/2014/09/08/c-6-0-primary-constructors/

Comment: It looks like primary constructors will be coming back in the form of [records](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/records.md) in C# 8.

Answer (score 1):

```
Class myClass
{
  private string field1 {get; set;}

  public Class()
  {
  }
}
```

Thats it, you now have a property if you initialize this class.
If you want it readonly, only write a get method.

Comment: actually, I think this looks like what the OP wants.

Comment: @UnholySheep This is a read only property if you only define a get method. So what is your problem?

Comment: I don't see any mention of "readonly" in OP's question, just `private`, this seems like it answers the question to me.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Before some comments + edit, there was the (probably mistaken) use of 'readonly'

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT (after question edit)

If you want a **dependency injection syntactic sugar in the constructor** as in Angular, unfortunately there aren't any ... yet .

---

To declare a `private` field in a class:

```
Class myClass
{
  private string field1;

  public Class()
  {
  }
}
```

if you want to be able to initilialize this field with a constructor call, you can give a parameter to the constructor so it can initialize it.

```
Class myClass
{
  private string field1;

  public Class(string field1)
  {
      this.field1 = field1;
  }
}
```

you can also define it as a property instead of a simple field (properties have getter and / or setters, and are internally backed by a hidden variable in C# with the below syntax) :

```
Class myClass
{
  private string Field1 { get; set; }

  public Class(string field1)
  {
      this.Field1 = field1;
  }
}
```

Comment: For a better understanding: If you write { get; set; } C# will automatically create a getter and a setter method for this property in this class.